# Forwarding a request in Spring WebFlow

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

Currently my application logic is using request parameters to execute the logic. In my new requirement I can also get a request that will only have a db key(db will have the values) as a request parameter. I can fetch the data from database but the problem is now my existing logic/flow will not work as it expects the data in parametermap.

In spring-mvc I can just forward the request again and append the parameters to request

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/test")
    public String showTestPage() {
        return "forward:/test2?param1=foo&param2=bar";
    }
}

@Controller
public class TestController2 {
    @RequestMapping(value="/test2")
    public String showTestPage(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String param1 = request.getParameter("param1");
        String param2 = request.getParameter("param2");
        return "testPageView";
    }
}
```

But in spring-webflow I am not sure how to replicate the same behavior as it works on states instead of request mapping. Can anyone please let me know if there is a way to forward in spring-webflow after adding parameters.

Comment: are the variables param1 and 2 `null`or what is your error? you are not using webflow at this point! just spring-mvc

Comment: I read this as the example of how he/she does it in SpringMVC, asking how to do the equivalent in Web Flow?

Comment: @Philipp: dbreaux is right I am asking the webflow equivalent for the code written in SpringMVC

Comment: show us your flow xml.

Comment: found a solution? let us know!

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Sorry i got your question wrong.

In WebFlow you have `view-states` which have transitions to the next state. If you want to transmit parameters you can do it like this:

flow.xml:

```
<view-state id="test" view="test.jsp>
    <transition on="toTest2" to="test2" />
</view-state>

<view-state id="test2" view="test2.jsp>
    <on-render>
        <evaluate expression="test2Delegate.doSomething(requestParameters.param2, requestParameters.param2)" 
    </on-render>
</view-state>
```

Test.jsp:

```
<a href="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=toTest2&param1=foo&param2=bar" />
```

Java:

```
@Component
public class Test2Delegate {

    public void doSomething(String param1, String param2) {

        //doSomething
    }
}
```

I would recommend read the [Spring Web Flow Reference Guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html)

Comment: Hi, Philipp, as mentioned in above comment the code I have written is in Spring-MVC and that works.. What I want to know is how do the same thing using spring-webflow

Comment: This will still not solve my problem as I want values to be present in parameterMap.. Basically parameters are immutable. Taking ur example I want "param1" and "param2" to be available in request parameters.

Comment: Thanks Philipp this should work but the only problem will be that we will have to display one more dummy page to user on which he has to click a button or even if we click the button using js without user input. But that will mean another server hit. I was hoping to do it without going to browser again.

Comment: ah okay! that should also be possible

Answer (score 0):

In flow xml add this :

```
<view-state id="viewname" view="flowRedirect:appName?#{flowScope.jobId}
```

so when you transit to this view state it will redirect the url back to server with the request params you want. But this will hit the web and then the server again, I want the request to stay on the server side only